# SpriteKit & Swift, make Platforms nil if a condition is true wont work

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-physics

Hi im making a simple 2d sidescroller game in spritekit with swift and im facing a problem that i cant solve. I have a function called (createPlatforms) to spawn some platforms  (each one above the other) and the Platforms are going form right to left. I also added a Bool variable called isJumping, i want that if the variable isJumping is true that the platforms physicsbody's gets nil so that the player can jump above it and land on it. I kinda managed to do that. It works on the first platform but not on the others. The Player jumps above the first Platform and lands on it but he cant jump above the second or third platform. Sometimes like 10% of the time it works on all platforms and he can jump above and land on them but most of the time it doesnt work.

Thank you in advance.

My jump method:

```
func jump() {

    isJumping = true

    let jumpBlock = SKAction.runBlock({
        () in
        self.Dragon.physicsBody?.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
        self.Dragon.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(0, 140))  // Jump Impulse
    })

    self.runAction(jumpBlock)

    runAfterDelay(0.3) { /* 0.3 Seconds */ 
        self.isJumping = false 
    }
}
 //Delay function
 func runAfterDelay(delay: NSTimeInterval, block: dispatch_block_t) {
    let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
}
```

}

Method for spawning platforms:

```
 func createPlatforms() {

    Platform1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Platform")
    Platform2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Platform")
    Platform3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"Platform-Small")

    Platform1.size = CGSize(width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 25)
    Platform2.size = CGSize(width: frame.width / 3, height: frame.height / 25)
    Platform3.size = CGSize(width: frame.width / 6, height: frame.height / 25)
    Platform1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width + 330, y: self.frame.height - 285)
    Platform2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width + 500, y: self.frame.height - 210)
    Platform3.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width + 570, y: self.frame.height - 135)

    Platform1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Platform1.size)
    Platform1.zPosition = 6
    Platform1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Platform1
    Platform1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
    Platform1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
    Platform1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    Platform2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Platform2.size)
    Platform2.zPosition = 7
    Platform2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Platform2
    Platform2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
    Platform2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
    Platform2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    Platform3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Platform3.size)
    Platform3.zPosition = 8
    Platform3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Platform3
    Platform3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
    Platform3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
    Platform3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false

    Platform1.runAction(moveAndRemove)
    Platform2.runAction(moveAndRemove)
    Platform3.runAction(moveAndRemove)

    self.addChild(Platform1)
    self.addChild(Platform2)
    self.addChild(Platform3)

    let distance = CGFloat(self.frame.width + 1000)
    let moveGroundObjects = SKAction.moveByX(-distance * 1.3, y: 0, duration: NSTimeInterval(0.011 * distance))
    let removeGroundObjects = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    moveAndRemove = SKAction.sequence([moveGroundObjects, removeGroundObjects])


    runAfterDelay(7) {
        self.createPlatforms()
    }
}
```

Method to make platforms's physicbody's nil:

```
func makePlatformsNil() {

    if isJumping == true {

        Platform1.physicsBody = nil
        Platform2.physicsBody = nil
        Platform3.physicsBody = nil

    }  else if isJumping == false {

        Platform1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize:  Platform1.size)
        Platform1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Platform1
        Platform1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
        Platform1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
        Platform1.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        Platform1.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false

        Platform2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Platform2.size)
        Platform2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Platform2
        Platform2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
        Platform2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
        Platform2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        Platform2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false

        Platform3.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: Platform3.size)
        Platform3.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Platform3
        Platform3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
        Platform3.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
        Platform3.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        Platform3.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    }
}
```

Please can someone help me? Im stuck since three weaks and im really frustrated right now :-/ Im sure my problem can be solved easily by someone with more experience with coding than me

Comment: When is makePlatformsNil called in your app?

Comment: do not nil out the body,  that means you will have to constantly recreate it,  very inefficient

Comment: if you want to handle platforms, just handle it on the didbegincontact,  by default, platforms should have collission mask bit for player turned off,  then on contact of player and platform, check the velocity of the player,  if it is downwards velocity,  turn the mask on,  then on the didendcontact,  turn it back off

Comment: no need for isjumping flag or anything like that,  and will also handle states where the sprite is falling without a jump action

Comment: @Ali Beadle in the update function

Comment: @Knight0fDragon i understand what you're saying but its kinda hard for me to code that cause im very new to programming, for example how do i check the velocity of the player? please please help me with a code example

Comment: You are using physics with gravity right?  sprite.physicsBody!.velocity

Comment: @Knight0fDragon and how do i determine if its downwards velocity?

Comment: you check the y value is negative

Comment: @Knight0fDragon thank you very much, im gonna try this now and post the result

Comment: @Knight0fDragon when i typed if player.physicsBody?.velocity <= -0 it gave me this error: "Cannot convert value of type CGVector? to expected argument type Int" - so i tried it with if player.physicsBody?.velocity.dy <= -0 and the error was gone. I did exactly what you said in the didBeginContact and didEndContact and it worked :-)). Thank you very very much!

Comment: no problem,  now it should be running smoother doing it this way

Comment: it really does! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a lot less code, that is cleaner and easier to manage.  (All platforms should share the same category, and Dragon category needs to be less than Platform)

Note: not tested for validation on XCode

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let (firstBody,secondBody) = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? (contact.bodyA,contact.bodyB) : (contact.bodyB,contact.bodyA) 

    // check if on Platform

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform)  {

        if firstBody.velocity.dy < -0.0 {

            secondBody.collisionBitMask |= physicsCatagory.Dragon
        }

    }



}

func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let (firstBody,secondBody) = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? (contact.bodyA,contact.bodyB) : (contact.bodyB,contact.bodyA) 

    // check if on Platform

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform)  {

       //No matter what way dragon is moving, if he is off the platform,  let's turn off the collision

            secondBody.collisionBitMask &= ~(physicsCatagory.Dragon)


    }

}
```

Comment: i'll try to implement that code to my project but its a little bit hard to read for me. What do you mean with Dragon category needs to be less than Platform? And does it make a difference to put the if statements in parentheses ? I have never done that

Comment: sometimes it matters to have parenthesis,  when you made your physicsCategory enum,  dragon needs to be before platform, so value of dragon is 1  platform 2 garbage 4 etc

Comment: Oh, ok. No i didn't make an enum, i did it with a struct like this: static let Dragon : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1, static let Ground : UInt32 = 0x1 << 2, static let Platform1 : UInt32 = 0x1 << 3 etc.

Comment: And i tried to implement your code but it gave me 3 times the same error. In didBeginContact & didEndContact. The error says: "Value of type 'SKPhysicsBody' has no member 'physicsBody'". On these three lines: --if firstBody.physicsBody?.velocity.dy < -0.0 { -- secondBody.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask |= physicsCatagory.Dragon --secondBody.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask &= ~(physicsCatagory.Dragon)

Comment: The old code still works though, so i did it like you said and made all Platforms the same Category. The code was much shorter but if the Dragon was on the first Platform he couldn't get on the second one. Somehow he still collided with the second Platform. Same goes for the second and third Platform

Comment: Yeah, i fixed it,  physicsbodies do not have physicsbodies

Comment: Well of course, because in old code you are forcing it to touch al 3 platforms, when you only want to touch the platform that the dragon touches

Comment: Struct enum doesnt matter, just as long as dragon value is lower than platform,  this means he will always be first

Comment: Ok, so i've implemented the new code and there are no error's now, but the Dragon doesn't collide with the platforms

Comment: did you change the contactTestBitMask to be platform?

Comment: Yes i did, Dragon's contactTestBitMask is Platform & Platform's contactTestBitMask is Dragon

Comment: is the begin contact firing?  and the collision failing?

Comment: i tested it right now, the contact is firing but the collision is failing, thats strange

Comment: Does Dragon have platform as a collisionbitmask?

Comment: No it doesnt, i've added it now but the Dragon cant jump above the Platforms anymore he's just colliding with them. In the old code the collisionBitMask of the Dragon has only Ground in it. Platforms are added in didBeginContact method. Can we move this discussion  to chat?

Comment: I do not see the link,  usually one pops up,  I do not know if you have the credentials for it.  Platform shouldnt be on dragpm,  platform should collide with dragon, and dragon should be pushed up.  Is your platform dynamic turned off?

Comment: Yes dynamic is turned off

Comment: OK, that needs to be on, and affectedbygravity turned off

Comment: You're right, i need a reputation of 20 to be able to chat

Comment: Hmm... I've set dynamic to false, affectedByGravity to false and allowsRotation to false but if the Dragon jumps on the platform it just falls down, and he cant jump through it because its colliding and the Platform is flying up

Comment: no you want dynamic on the platform to be true, hmm  is there anyway you can get me the source?

Comment: Why has it to be true? In the old code its off and it works fine. Sure, can i send it to you via email?

Comment: because colission does not get evaluated on non dynamic bodies,  normally it would be the dragon you would be doing the check on,  but this  fails when it comes to staircase designed platforms,  so you turn it on the individual platforms,  But I think we need to make is so that they do no move

Comment: Hmm.. I think i will just use the old code, it works fine and i its only a little bit longer than the new one. I've got another question if you don't mind, i've read that its better to make classes for my project, you know for the dragon, platforms, world objects etc. I've done that but now the dragon and the platforms don't collide anymore although i've set it up in the didBeginContact method. Can you help me with that? And after i created the class and removed the dragon from the gamescene file the performance of the game changed too, it runs with only 20fps instead of 30

Comment: old way will get you errors in the future, like not enough categories.  Once I see the code I will be able to get you on the right path, so hard with hypotheticals.  You only need to make classes if they do something beyond what the base class does,  The Dragon should have a class,  Platforms and world objects would not need one

Comment: Oh ok. Do you want me to send you the project via email or should i just upload the whole code here? I can edit my question and put the code there if you want

Comment: OH and i made a typo when i wrote this : Hmm... I've set dynamic to false, affectedByGravity to false and allowsRotation to false -- i didn't set dynamic to false i set it to true like you wanted. thats why the platforms were moving when they collided with the Dragon. sorry for that mistake

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else faces the same problem, @Knight0fDragon knew the solution to my question. As he said, what i did was very inefficient. Its way better not to have a collisionBitMask between the platform and the player by default and to turn it on when the velocity of the player is negative and turn it off again in the didEndContact method.

Thank you again @Knight0fDragon, i was struggling with this problem for weeks.

Here's the code that did it for me:

```
 func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
    let firstBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB

    // check if on Platform

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform1 || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform1 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon) {

        if Dragon.physicsBody?.velocity.dy <= -0.0 {

            Platform1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
            Dragon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Platform1

        }

    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform2 || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform2 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon) {

        if Dragon.physicsBody?.velocity.dy <= -0.0 {

            Platform2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
            Dragon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Platform2

        }

    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform3 || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform3 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon) {

        if Dragon.physicsBody?.velocity.dy <= -0.0 {

            Platform3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Dragon
            Dragon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Platform3

        }
    }


}

func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    let firstBody = contact.bodyA
    let secondBody = contact.bodyB


    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform1 || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform1 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon) {

        Platform1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
        Dragon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground
}

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform2 || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform2 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon) {

        if Dragon.physicsBody?.velocity.dy <= -0.0 {

            Platform2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
            Dragon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground

        }

    }

    if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform3 || firstBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Platform3 && secondBody.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCatagory.Dragon) {

        if Dragon.physicsBody?.velocity.dy <= -0.0 {

            Platform3.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0
            Dragon.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCatagory.Ground

        }
    }
```

}
}

Comment: is Dragon your main character?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Yes, why are you asking? :-)

Comment: for the answer I gave you